# How can I determine the local machine's IP addresses from Perl?

Tags: perl, networking

Is there a clean and OS independent way to determine the local machine's IP addresses from Perl?

So far I have found the following solutions:

- parse the output of ifconfig and ipconfig (hard, different windows versions have different ipconfig outputs)
- establish a network connection to a well-known IP and examine the socket's local IP address (won't work if I can't establish a connection and will determine only one IP address)

Any better suggestion?

Comment: The magic number is 127.0.0.1

Comment: That's not what I need. I just want to print out the machine's IP addresses in a customized form, I don't want to use the addresses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Net::Address::IP::Local](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Address::IP::Local) looks promising.

```
use Net::Address::IP::Local;

# Get the local system's IP address that is "en route" to "the internet":
my $address      = Net::Address::IP::Local->public;
```

Comment: new link http://search.cpan.org/~jmehnle/Net-Address-IP-Local-0.1.2/lib/Net/Address/IP/Local.pm

Comment: Made the link version independent ;-)

Comment: @zizzencs I don't understand why you accepted the answer as you asked for *all* the IP addresses of the machine. This answer returns just one.

Answer (score 18):

You also have some [other options](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=53660), including your solution to "establish a network connection to a well-known IP and examine the socket's local IP address".

In that case (establishing network connection) however, that article points out that:

> there is no such thing as a host's IP address.
> Network interfaces have IP addresses, not hosts, and a single network interface can have many (virtual) IP addresses. The operating system's routing subsystem decides which network interface and IP address to use to connect to a remote machine.
>
> If your machine only has one external network interface, and this interface only has one IP address then this IP address is commonly called the machine's address, but that is inaccurate.
> For example, if the machine is connected to a VPN via a virtual interface it will use this interface's IP address to connect to another machine on the VPN, not the external IP address

Amongst the other solutions: [`Sys::Hostname`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Sys::Hostname) - works if it comes up with a resolvable hostname.

```
use Sys::Hostname;
use Socket;
my $addr = inet_ntoa((gethostbyname(hostname))[4]);
print "$addr\n";
```

Comment: These too are nice solutions that won't work in all cases. I will create a custom solution combining these if there's not a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @zb226 Thank you for the edit, much appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I need a solution without any non-core dependencies.  I came up with this after studying the code in Net::Address::IP::Local:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $local_ip_address = get_local_ip_address();

print "$local_ip_address\n";

# This idea was stolen from Net::Address::IP::Local::connected_to()
sub get_local_ip_address {
    my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Proto       => 'udp',
        PeerAddr    => '198.41.0.4', # a.root-servers.net
        PeerPort    => '53', # DNS
    );

    # A side-effect of making a socket connection is that our IP address
    # is available from the 'sockhost' method
    my $local_ip_address = $socket->sockhost;

    return $local_ip_address;
}
```

`get_local_ip_address()` should return the same string as `Net::Address::IP::Local->public_ipv4`.

If desired, you can change the `PeerAddr` attribute (in the arguments to the constructor for IO::Socket::INET) to a local DNS server.

Comment: -1 as copy/paste is not the recommended way of developing with Perl.

Comment: @dolmen Agreed.  If it helps my case at all, the script I wrote was used as a cron job, deployed to development boxes to keep DNS records active.  If I revisited it, I would consider [fatpacking](https://metacpan.org/module/fatpack) Net::Address::IP::Local into the script instead. >=D

Comment: @dolmen Easy on the -1. This kind of thing helps people who are not familiar with perl and just want to get it done.

Comment: Abuse of a root nameserver and fragile since these addresses can and do change.

Answer (score 7):

To retrieve the IP address of *all* interfaces, use [IO::Interface::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Interface::Simple):

```
perl -MIO::Interface::Simple '-Esay $_->address for grep { $_->is_running && defined $_->address } IO::Interface::Simple->interfaces'
```

If you are not interested in 127.0.0.1 (loopback) you can filter on `$_->is_loopback`.

Answer (score 3):

Perldoc has an [answer to this question in its FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-find-out-my-hostname%2c-domainname%2c-or-IP-address%3f) ("perlfaq9") - using different modules (which are parts of the Standard Library) or even a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success with [IO::Interface](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Interface) on Linux and Solaris, and I think it even worked on AIX but I can't recall for sure. Poking around on search.cpan.org, rt.cpan.org and ActiveState's various sites, it looks like IO::Interface may be experiencing build problems on Windows. I guess the only way to know if it's available is to search for io-interface in PPM.

Answer (score 0):

use WMI?

[Example of extracting IP addresses](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine141.htm) (in Powershell, but it's pretty clear what's happening)

[Example of accessing WMI from Perl](http://talhatariq.wordpress.com/2006/06/09/a-perl-wmi-script-for-fetching-local-remote-os-info/) (not the same WMI functions, but again the process is reasonably clear)

EDIT: after a search on Google codesearch for Networkadapterconfiguration and language "perl":

[Example looks like pretty much what you need](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&q=networkadapterconfiguration+lang:perl+show:S-o7TNXPu0g:7J-KcLWeJok:S-o7TNXPu0g&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc&cs_p=cvs+:pserver:anonymous%40ocsinventory.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/ocsinventory+.&cs_f=unified_unix_agent/lib/Ocsinventory/Agent/Backend/OS/Win32/Networks.pm)

EDIT2: In fact the OCS code seems to contain code for most platforms to do this, so while there may be no one set of code that does this, you may be able to re-use their ideas. It's GPL'd, though.

For example, [here's the Solaris code](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&q=show:DmOgK1BEY5s:FzZZCRcA3DU:DmOgK1BEY5s&sa=N&ct=rd&cs_p=cvs+:pserver:anonymous%40ocsinventory.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/ocsinventory+.&cs_f=unified_unix_agent/lib/Ocsinventory/Agent/Backend/OS/Solaris.pm). Other bits cover BSD, Linux, MacOS...

Comment: Looks promising, but afaik WMI is not available on most linux systems. Sure you can use OpenPegasus, but that would be a little bit too big for this problem.

Comment: No, WMI wouldn't be. Looks like you may need to switch on OS type and have different code.

Comment: I will do that if nothing else helps. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The Google Code search links are broken.

Comment: Yes. Google codesearch is no more. I don't have an updated source

Answer (score 0):

[getting a network interface's IP address in Perl without additional modules usage and 'ifconfig' output parsing](http://snipplr.com/view/46170/the-most-reliable-and-correct-method-to-get-network-interface-address-in-linux-using-perl/)

Answer (score 0):

Net::Address::IP::Local works fine, but since the original poster asks for all the local addresses, I think this one is better:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=166951

It worked fine for me with ActivePerl for Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

for windows I use

```
foreach (split(/\r?\n/,`netstat -r`))
{
  next unless /^\s+0.0.0.0/;
  @S = split(/\s+/); 
  # $S[3] = Default Gateway
  # $S[4] = Main IP
}
```

The first line starting 0.0.0.0 is the default gateway. There maybe multiple gateways.
Lines starting 255.255.255.255 are also useful. netstat -r and route print are the same.

Can be adapted for OSX, Linux not so helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I have used a combination of these Linux commands so no dependancy on any perl module.

```
hostname -i
hostname -I
ls /sys/class/net
ip -f inet addr show eth0| grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'
```