# Detect and Display computer IP Address

Tags: perl

Can anyone please tell me how to detect and display computer IP Address using Perl.

Thanks in advance. Please help.

Code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use IO::Socket;
$hostname="(my hostname)"; 
my($addr)=inet_ntoa((gethostbyname($hostname))[4]);
print "$addr\n";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330458/how-can-i-determine-the-local-machines-ip-addresses-from-perl

Comment: Which one? Computers rarely have only one address. Why do you want it?

Comment: @user2201935 You've now shown us the code you are using, but please include the exception you are getting as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for

```
use CGI qw( );
my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->header('text/plain');
print $cgi->remote_addr(), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google gave me the following information

> To get the IP address, you can use the gethostbyname built-in function
>   to turn the name into a number. To turn that number into the dotted
>   octet form (a.b.c.d) that most people expect, use the inet_ntoa
>   function from the Socket module, which also comes with perl.

```
use Socket;
my $address = inet_ntoa(
        scalar gethostbyname( $host || 'localhost' )
);
```

More examples: [Perldoc, how do I find my hostname, domainname or IP](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-find-out-my-hostname,-domainname,-or-IP-address?%20%22How%20do%20I%20find%20out%20my%20hostname,%20domainname%20or%20IP)